# Does the asyncio event loop only run tasks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I’m in the early stages of learning about the asyncio library. I'm starting off with coroutines and tasks, and reading through the *hello world* examples in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines).

Based on the section about coroutines, it seems there are two main ways of running a coroutine object:

- Using `await` on a coroutine
- Running coroutines as asyncio [Tasks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task)

According to the [Task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task) docs:

> Tasks are used to run coroutines in event loops.

To be clear, does this imply the event loop doesn't run coroutine objects unless they are wrapped into a task? In this situation, are these coroutine objects just run synchronously without any interaction with the event loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To be clear, does this [that tasks are used to run coroutines] imply the event loop doesn't run coroutine objects unless they are wrapped into a task?

It means that tasks are the entry point into the coroutine world. Each coroutine can be traced to being awaited by an outer coroutine, all the way to a coroutine that is driven by a task.

Take this example code:

```
async def inner():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def outer():
    await inner()
    await inner()

async def main():
    await outer()

asyncio.run(main())
```

`asyncio.run` implicitly creates one task to drive the `main` coroutine to completion. The task only "sees" the coroutine object created by invoking `main()` and is unconcerned with the coroutine `main` awaits. From the point of view of the task, `main` will suspend twice, once for each `sleep`. Prior to suspending, the `sleep` coroutine will arrange with the event loop for the task to be resumed.

> In this situation, are these coroutine objects just run synchronously without any interaction with the event loop?

All coroutines must interact with the event loop because they must be able to *suspend*. If they are awaited by another coroutine, they cause the awaiting coroutine to suspend. This propagates up to the top-level coroutine which is run by a task, and that causes the task to suspend.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a terrific answer. Am I understanding you correctly by saying:  1. A coroutine belongs to a task.  2. Coroutines aren’t suspended and resumed. Tasks are suspended and resumed.  3. The event loop interacts with both coroutines and tasks.  4. A coroutine informs the event loop of when its task should be suspended.  5. The event loop suspends and resumes tasks.

Comment: Mostly correct, although details could matter. #2 - a coroutine definitely suspends, it's just that it immediately (and transparently) propagates the suspension across the await stack all the way to the task. #3 depends on what you mean by "interact". The event loop only schedules callbacks, and tasks are one source of callbacks (the only one that runs anything `async def` coroutines). To learn more about the mechanism behind await, take a look at e.g. [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7JtNiwCH_OA), or [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCs5OvhV9S4).

Comment: Both lectures were some of the most useful presentations I've seen on any topic. Thank you again for you help.

Comment: An addendum: all tasks and coroutines are always running/suspending as long as the loop is running.  Await is just a way to block the code following it.